# MIN and MAX in SQL for given item type and quality

Tags: mysql

I have always been curious about if there is a better way to do the following:

Suppose I have a table of shoes being sold, there are some Nike, Adidas, Teva, Steve Madden
etc.

```
CREATE TABLE Shoes(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    brand int not null, /* NIKE: 1, ADIDAS: 2, TEVA: 4, STEVE_MADDEN: 8 */
    quality int not null /* NEW: 1, USED: 2*/
    price datetime not null,
    posted timestamp default current_timestamp
);
```

Now I want to see the lowest and the highest price of a given brand and the quality. So 
this is what I have but I wanted to know if there is a better way to do it, considering 
a very large database.

Let's say I want to know the highest and lowest price for NIKE shoes (new and used ) I 
would do the following:

```
SELECT MIN(price) AS lowest, MAX(price) AS highest FROM Shoes WHERE brand = 1 AND quality = 1;
SELECT MIN(price) AS lowest, MAX(price) AS highest FROM Shoes WHERE brand = 1 AND quality = 2;
```

is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with one query and this return 2 rows and one field more.

```
SELECT quality, MIN(price) AS lowest, 
  MAX(price) AS highest
FROM Shoes 
WHERE
    brand = 1 
AND 
    quality IN(1,2)
GROUP BY quality
ORDER BY quality;
```

**sample with join**

```
SELECT quality, MIN(s.price) AS lowest,
 MAX(s.price) AS highest,
 t.OneField
FROM Shoes s
LEFT JOIN YourTable t ON s.brand = t.TheBrandField
WHERE
    s.brand = 1 
AND 
    s.quality IN(1,2)
GROUP BY s.quality
ORDER BY quality;
```

Comment: If I wanted to joined it with a table with info related to each brand how could i do that? I know I could joined but that would be repetitive adding the same info on each row!

Comment: @Gacci - i have add a sample with join in my answer

Comment: wouldn't that give me a extra info on each row!

Comment: yes - see now . t.OneField is the info from the joined table

Comment: I mean like extra columns (columns from the joined table)

Comment: use t.* instead  t.OneField to see all field from the joined table

Comment: But I don't want extra info from the joined table o be repeated on every row. So let's say I want info about a book, I want the info about the book (title, isbn, authors, etc.) But I also want the info (price, quality, seller) about the books being sold. So, I don't want to have 100 books and on each have price, quality, seller, PLUS title, isbn, authors, etc. I want the info about the books only once and then the info about each respective book!